# Signing data using openssl with python

Tags: python, openssl, cryptography

I am currently signing data using next `opensll` command:

```
openssl dgst -sign key.pem -sha256 -out signature.sig data.txt
```

How can I achieve this with Python?

Comment: `import os; os.system(cmd)`.

Comment: @BarunSharma I know it and thank you, but question in another how would I do it with a python functions, libraries?

Comment: Did you try some luck with `openssl`python library.

Comment: @BarunSharma I found answer:) Thank you for support!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found answer here(http://nullege.com/ and https://pyopenssl.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html):

```
import OpenSSL
from OpenSSL import crypto
import base64
key_file = open("C:\my.pem", "r")
key = key_file.read()
key_file.close()
password = "password of prk"

if key.startswith('-----BEGIN '):
    pkey = crypto.load_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, key, password)
else:
    pkey = crypto.load_pkcs12(key, password).get_privatekey()
print pkey
data = "data"
sign = OpenSSL.crypto.sign(pkey, data, "sha256") 
print sign

data_base64 = base64.b64encode(sign)
print data_base64
```